# Cannot terminate or kill subprocess after building .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, terminate

Terminating the following subprocess in the ways I described below works great when executing the script with python. However, after using pyinstaller to build a .exe file, the blender process is not terminated.

```
bpy_script_path = os.path.join(main_dir, 'Packages', 'Scripts', 'BlenderRendering', 'bpy_script.py')
blender_command = [blender_executable, '--background','--python', bpy_script_path]

if os.name == 'nt':
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000
    blender_process = subprocess.Popen(blender_command, creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
else:
    blender_process = subprocess.Popen(blender_command)
            
while blender_process.poll() == None:
    try:
        msg = queue.get_nowait()
        if msg[0] == 'kill':
            #tried first
            blender_process.kill()
            blender_process.wait()
            
            #tried second
            blender_process.terminate()
            blender_process.wait()

            #tried third
            subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(blender_process.pid)])
            
            queue.put(('kill successful', None, None))
            return False
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

The code snippet I provided is part of a script that is being run as a multiprocess. Therefore, the communication via queue. I want to terminate/kill the blender process, when the main application is being closed. As the main application waits for the 'kill successful' message upon closing, not being able to terminate the blender process leads to the main_window running in a loop waiting for the message of successful termination. I also tried using psutil, but that doesn't work neither. Not sure what to do at this point..

```
while blender_process.poll() == None:
    msg = None
    try:
        msg = queue.get_nowait()
    except:
        pass
    if msg:
        if msg[0] == 'kill':
            subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(blender_process.pid)])
            queue.put(('kill successful', None, None))
            return False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What is your Operating System? Is it Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows, hence the line: if os.name == 'nt':

Comment: Well, that `try: except: pass` is preventing you from seeing the error. Might want to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, as @AKX said, please remove that and consider debugging

Comment: I assume your error is probably because you haven't specified stdin, stdout and stderr and have built the exe with the noconsole flag? As mentioned by AKX remove that try-except and see or atleast output information about the exception.

Comment: Well, the `try: except: pass` statement is necessary, because `queue.get_nowait()` raises an exception, if there is no message put in the queue. When executing with python, using this version: `subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/F', '/T', '/PID', str(blender_process.pid)])` I get this output:
SUCCESS: The process with PID 22112 (child process of PID 8792) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8792 (child process of PID 5952) has been terminated.
That shows that blender and the terminal it automatically creates could both be terminated.

Comment: Anyways, I restructured it. Appended it to my question, because the formatting is pretty confusing as a comment.
still not working, how can I retrieve an error message if it is running in a multiprocess?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes that is what I did actually. Do I have to specify stdin, stdout and stderr? Or what might cause the error?

Comment: For the record, I don't actually know if there is an exception at all. What I was thinking is that blender_process.wait() just waits for the termination of the process infinitely.

Comment: If you don't specify those the subprocess inherits it from the parent. Given you've used noconsole the parent doesn't have it either which might cause an error, check the error you are getting.

Comment: Excuse me, the error was due to something completely different. The messages that were sent to the multiprocessing queue were read at several places at the same time. So the kill message was no longer in the queue when it was requested. Finally I replaced the queue with 2 multiprocessing events. Now everything works fine! Should I delete the question?

Comment: @MasterOfDesaster42 You should just self-answer it.

Answer (score 0):

All three solutions mentioned in the question are working perfectly fine for terminating a multiprocess. The problem was rather the communication between the different processes. As multiple processes accessed the multiprocessing queue at the same time without synchronization, some signals/messages did not reach their supposed destination. In this case especially the 'kill' message did not get through as another loop in the main process that checks the queue already received the message.The problem was resolved using two multiprocessing events (main_window_close & blender_terminated) instead of relying on the same queue that is also used for other communication:

```
while blender_process.poll() == None:
    if main_window_close.is_set():
        blender_process.terminate()
        blender_process.wait()
        blender_terminated.set()
        return False
    time.sleep(1)
```